# How to get detected image coordinates/image object from core ml model response?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, object-detection, coreml, coremltools

I am working on object detection using Vision framework and core ml model. I got success to detect object with this.

But in my case i want to fetch detected image in response not only object name and confidence.

Ex. Try to identify banana through camera and model class returns banana and confidence level. But i also want banana image from it. But model class has no output property to return it. i am using Inceptionv3 model for this.

Is there any other model class for this purpose ?